# Is it okay to copy and paste a grunt directory?

Tags: gruntjs

I have a Grunt setup on my machine that's running SASS, Compass, Watch, Uglify... that kind of stuff. I've installed it using the command line (npm install...) from a tutorial.

I want to create a Grunt folder for another project. Is it okay to just copy that first folder and change the names? Is there some reason I should install the new one from the command line as well?

Answer (score 0):

it will depends on what *context* you installed if  was **local or globally (-g)**.

If you installed locally without -g option, you are find to copy and past the folders.

However, would be a great practice to reuse only the **package.json** file and run the command, for your next project:

> $ npm install

Comment: I tried that, but when I do, it seems to install a whole bunch of other node modules that I don't need.

Comment: check if the package.json, has only what you need... don't forget the decencies for each module.

Comment: Yeah, it certainly looks like the package.json file has far fewer modules than were installed.